# Can we make extrapolations about functional properties from differential properties?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let's suppose we know $$\frac{d}{dx} f(x) = f(x)$$

Is there then a way to extrapolate information about the nature of $f(x)$, how it might treat sums and products by knowing this? For instance, is there anything about the differential equation itself that could prove $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ or $f(ax) = f(x)^a$ or anything of the sort?

The reason I'm asking about this to start with is for more complicated situations.

Comment: Not necessarily functional properties, but one can derive many classes of bounds on the growth of $f$ from Gronwall's inequality: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality

Answer (score 2):

Yes. For example, we compute that

$$\frac{d}{dx} f(x + y) = f(x + y)$$

from which it follows that, as a function of $x$, $f(0) f(x + y)$ satisfies the differential equation $\frac{d}{dx} g(x) = g(x)$ with initial condition $g(0) = f(0) f(y)$. But this is also true of $f(x) f(y)$. It follows that

$$\boxed{ f(0) f(x + y) = f(x) f(y) }$$

and if $f(0) = 1$ then we just get $f(x + y) = f(x) f(y)$ as expected of the exponential.

Similarly we compute that

$$\frac{d}{dx} f(ax) = a f(ax)$$

from which it follows that, as a function of $x$, $f(0)^{a-1} f(ax)$ satisfies the differential equation $\frac{d}{dx} g(x) = a g(x)$ with initial condition $g(0) = f(0)^a$. But, as above, this is also true of $f(x)^a$. This gives

$$\boxed{ f(0)^{a-1} f(ax) = f(x)^a }$$

and if $f(0) = 1$ we get $f(ax) = f(x)^a$, again as expected of the exponential.

Comment: Interesting, thank you for sharing these techniques!

Comment: Actually, I'm struggling to replicate your first theorem. How do you know what $g(t)$ is? How do you know $f(0)$ goes on the outside like that? I'm missing quite a few steps to formalize your claims. How do you know you can pick $g(0) = f(0)f(y)$? What's going on here? Sorry, but there's too many unanswered questions for me to accept this as a legitimate process of exploring functional properties.

Comment: Yeah I have no idea whatsoever how you made you very bold claim that "this is true of $f(x)f(y).$" Where I'm at is I start with $\frac{d}{dx} f(x) = f(x).$ Now let $y$ be any real number with the very, very bold assumption that we know $f(y)$ is defined for all $y \in \mathbb{R}.$. Then it is further true that $\frac{d}{dx} f(x+y) = f(x+y).$ It is further true by the linearity of differential operators that $\frac{d}{dx} f(y)f(x+y) = f(y)f(x+y).$ Okay, now what?

Comment: @CheeseBlues: $f(0)$ is just being placed to match the initial conditions. $g(0) = f(0) f(y)$ follows from substituting $x = 0$. $y$ is being treated as a constant which is fixed but arbitrary, so $\frac{d}{dx} f(x) f(y) = f'(x) f(y) = f(x) f(y)$. This means that $g(x) = f(x) f(y)$ satisfies the same differential equation as $f(0) f(x + y)$ with the same initial condition, so the two functions are the same. I am assuming for simplicity that $f$ is defined everywhere, yes. If you don't want to assume that then you can say "when defined, we have..." or whatever.

Comment: Okay, so we start with $\frac{d}{dx} f(x) = f(x)$ with some initial condition $f_0 = f(0).$ Alright, so now then, if we assume $y$ is any constant, then it is also both true that $\frac{d}{dx} f(x+y) = f(x+y)$, and furthermore, that $\frac{d}{dx} f(x)f(y) = f(x)f(y)$. So far so good, these statements make sense so far. But now, how do we make the leap to saying $f(x+y) = f(x)f(y)$ by virtue of both satisfying the same differential equation?

Comment: @CheeseBlues: this is a general fact about first-order differential equations: their solutions are uniquely determined by their initial conditions. It follows from the Picard-Lindelof theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) but this special case probably admits a simpler proof.

Comment: Okay, I'm familiar with the uniqueness of ODE given an initial condition, but what I'm not seeing is how to connect that idea to what you're suggesting and what you wrote. So we know $f(x+y)$ and $f(x)f(y)$ both satisfy the same differential equation. What's the next step for me to prove $f(x+y) = f(x)f(y)$ up to some constant? I'm assuming this involves what you wrote, but I'm not 100% sure how.

Comment: @CheeseBlues: again, you need to think of $y$ as a constant. These are two functions of $x$, and as functions of $x$ they satisfy a first-order differential equation in $x$, and they have the same initial condition at $x = 0$. So by Picard-Lindelof they're equal. (This special case does have a much simpler proof which I can give if you want.)

Comment: What's missing though from my computations is how the "initial conditions" come into play, You wrote a broader statement than what I wrote involving the initial conditions of $g(x)$ and both $f(x).$ It was only after you did that did you mention the two variants are equal after manipulating the initial conditions.

Comment: Here's why I need to know what's going on with the initial conditions: the functions $e^x$ and $2e^x$ both satisfy the same differential equation, BUT, the functions $f(x) = e^x$ and $h(x) = 2e^x$ are *not the same function*. So to know for sure that I've avoided any ambiguity, I need to know how about the thought process of considering these initial conditions.

Comment: @CheeseBlues: they have different initial conditions. $e^0 = 1$ and $2e^0 = 2$. So this is not a problem. More generally $ce^x$ is the unique function satisfying $\frac{d}{dx} f(x) = f(x)$ with initial condition $f(0) = c$.

Comment: I'm still not seeing it, but maybe I just need time to sort through it.